# How to create javascript array and save another array data to created array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

create a javascript array and save another array of data to created an array in Javascript. I have tried it in the following mentioned way.

Code:

```
var vvv=this.new_products.length-this.quote.lines.length;
      let mmm={};
      if(vvv > 0){
        for(var i = 0; i <= vvv-1; i++){
          mmm ={...this.new_products[this.quote.lines.length+i]};
        }
      }
      console.log(mmm);
```

example:

```
this.new_products -> 
    0: {…}
    1: {…}
    2: {…}
    3: {…}
this.quote.lines ->
    0: {…}
    1: {…}
```

The output should be ->

```
mmm->
    0: {…} (this.new_products[2])
    1: {…} (this.new_products[3])
```

Current output->

```
{product_code: "khdbdvdjlhc de", description: "sscs", note: "csccc", pinned: false, third_party: 0, …}
```

My tried code is not working. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: It's not clear what you want. Give an exemple of input and what would be the desired result for that input.

Comment: console.log(mmm); this is undefined, mmm is out of the block where it was declared

Comment: @PedroLima I updated the question with what you expected.

Comment: @lissettdm I updated the question  with the expected output.

Comment: So, mmm should be this.new_products[2] right?

Comment: @lissettdm yes it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assumed that you need the remains items:

```
 let m = [];
 for(var i = 0; i <= vvv - 1; i++){
    m.push({...this.new_products[this.quote.lines.length+i]});
 }
```

Comment: I edited my tried code with your answer. But I am getting a new error now.
> Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Assignment to constant variable."

Comment: Yes, replace const mmm={}; for let mmm={};

Comment: Now it workes. But now there is another problem. The problem is now always saving inside `mmm` the last one. If there are 2 changes this adds only the last change. not both changes. How Can I solve this?

Comment: Can you add an example with the problem you are facing?

Comment: @user_v12 I updated my answer, I assumed that m is type of Array

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shallow copy by using the `...` spread operator like this:

`var array = ["thing1", "thing2"];`

`var array2 = [...array];`

If you need to make a deep copy, one of the easiest method is using lodash's cloneDeep() function like this:

`import _ from 'lodash';`

`var array = ["thing1", "thing2"];`

`var array2 = _.cloneDeep(array);`